# Why does my while loop freeze my program and how can it be fixed?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am very new to Java and have a question. My program is a simple guessing game with the computer. If you guess it correctly, then your points move up by 1. If you guess incorrectly, then your points decrease by 1. If you get to 7 or 0 then you win/lose. Could you help me understand why it doesnt loop back to where the while statement starts?
Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.io.*;

class RandomGame {
public static void main(String str[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userAns = new String();
    Random generator = new Random();

    int guess, num, points = 0;

    System.out.println("Hello...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    System.out.println("Would you consider playing a fun game?");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    userAns = scan.next();
    // if/else about whether they want to play the game**********
    if (userAns.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Awww yeah lets get going!");
        System.out
                .println("Objective of the game:\n1.Guess numbers out of 5\n2."
                        + "If you guess incorrect you get points reduced.\n3.Have fun!");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("\nReady?");
        userAns = scan.next();
        if (userAns.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Okay! Here we go!");
            // COUNTDOWN************************************
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("3");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }

        // *****************************************************
        System.out.println("Please enter a integer 1-5 to start the game.");

        guess = scan.nextInt();
        num = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;
        while (points <= 7 && points >= 0)

        {
            if (guess == num) {
                System.out.println("Correct! You gained 1 point!");
                points++;
                System.out.println(points);
            } else if (guess != num) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect. You lose 1 point.");
                points--;

            }
        }

    }

    else if (userAns.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("GAMEOVER.\n\n\nHint: say \"yes\"");
    }

    else {
        System.out.print("yes or no answers please.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Remove all irrelevant stuff from your program (that strangely looking countdown for starters). 2. Fix indentation. Then it will be readable and someone may answer.

Comment: Create a minimal failing example. Way too much code without focus. Anyway .. hint: *you only read the input (`guess`) once*.

Comment: Does it even compile? It seems like the brackets are not properly matched.

Comment: Yeah im really new to this stuff.

Comment: Thank you for all the speedy responses. I have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does loop back to where the while loop starts, It just doesn't read in the next guess as your read from the users input is outside the loop. These two lines need to be inside the loop

```
guess = scan.nextInt();
num = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;
```

Currently your code reads in one int and generates one. If the guess is correct you'll get 7 points and then win, if its wrong you'll lose immediatly

Answer (score 1):

If you get the answer wrong the first time, your points become -1.

```
while (points <= 7 && points >= 0)
```

Checks for ranges only between 0 and 7 and hence it quits the loop

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop isn't going to wait for the `nextInt()`, so the loop just increments or deincrements based on what the first guess was. To fix this, wait for the next input before doing a calculation, and do the calculations within the loop:

```
while ((points <= 7 && points >= 0) && scan.hasNext()) {
  // we have an input value
  guess = scan.nextInt();
  num = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take user input inside the while loop

```
  while (points <= 7 && points >= 0)
  {
      guess = scan.nextInt();
      num = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;
      // continue 

  }
```